# OSGI component initialization order with optional greedy

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I'm using Osgi DS (in AEM environment).

I have a service *A* provided by component *AImpl* that can but doesn't have to be active (it depends on presence of its configuration).

Some systems have it others don't but it's predetermined and known on boot time.

Now I have other components (let's say *BImpl*) that optionally use it with STATIC, OPTIONAL, GREEDY reference type.

Now, how can I ensure that the *Bimpl* will get it on the systems where it's active when it's first initialized during bootup. 
In other words how can I ensure *BImpl* will always be initialized after *AImpl* on systems where *AImpl* is supposed to be active?

I wan't to avoid the situation where there's no hard init dependency between *BImpl* and *AImpl* and *BImpl* gets initialized first and then restarted when *AImpl* is finally activated during bootup.

If possible I'd like to avoid utilizing startlevels (use of non-default startlevel is normally not recommended of user level components in AEM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main options here:

1. Don't worry about it. The fact that your BImpl has a *static greedy* reference means that when the AImpl is registered the BImpl will be injected with it, even if that means destroying and re-initializing the BImpl component. This is how things are supposed to work with static references, and is exactly what would happen if the AImpl were unregistered/updated.
2. Could the BImpl component be made to have a required configuration? If it can then you could use that configuration to change the minimum cardinality of the AImpl reference from zero to one. This would make it a mandatory reference and would ensure that your BImpl did not start until an AImpl was available. The configuration for the minimum cardinality of a reference is [defined in the specification](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-minimum.cardinality.property) and can be set dynamically using Configuration Admin.
3. Like 2, but create an APrimeImpl which implements A with a stubbed implementation and has a required configuration. Use this configuration to activate the stubbed A (or not) and then make BImpl (and all of the implementations) use a mandatory reference for A. This way you only have one configuration to change to force everyone to use a real AImpl. On the other hand you lose the ability to make some of the references mandatory and others optional.

Option 1 is definitely simplest, and is what I would normally recommend to people.

Comment: Thanks, I went for a variant of 3. What I can't allow is to have B service online without A on the systems where A is actually expected. That's because B behaves incorrectly and its results are cached by other services even after it's restarted to accommodate for now present A.